# xunit nuget package restore failed

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, xunit

I've come to a problem while trying asp.net vNext beta8. I'm running a working project but I wanted to add a unit test project next to it. I've found that you should add the xunit and xunit.runner.dnx nuget packages in the project.json. while typing, the intellisense continuous me so I see that the package must be downloaded from nuget. after saving the project.json i get the error in my output, which says: An error occurred while sending the request.

Does anyone else get this problem or does anyone know the solution?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you follow all steps from the guidelines at https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html? This worked well in my project, with beta7 and beta8.

Comment: It is a bit late of a response, but it appeared that the corporate proxy blocked the nuget sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem appeared to be a corporate proxy which didn't like visual studio and the nuget package manager. when working on the guest network I was able to restore all the packages.